# Unable to create next pages based on content in PDF generation from Template itextsharp

Tags: itext

I am using itextsharp for creating PDF . But when my content goes beyong 1 page it does not create and append text to next page. Below is my source code. Cannot identify whats goin wrong with this. Please guide.

```
    Dim pdfTemplate As String = "C:\Program Files\mycrm\Documents\Client\Statement_.pdf"
    Dim newFile As String = "D:\test.pdf"

    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)
    Dim pdfStamper As New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create))

    Dim pdfFormFields As AcroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields
    pdfFormFields.SetField("[CLIENT NAME]", "siddhesh")

    'For adding table
    Dim PdfTable As New PdfPTable(2)
    Dim PdfPCell As PdfPCell = Nothing

    For column As Integer = 0 To 1
        PdfPCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk(column.ToString())))
        PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell)
    Next

    For rows As Integer = 0 To 100
        For column As Integer = 0 To 1
            PdfPCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk(rows.ToString() + column.ToString())))
            PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell)
        Next
    Next
    PdfTable.HeaderRows = 1
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = True

    PdfTable.SetTotalWidth(New Single() {
 (iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate().Height - 25) / 10,
 (iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate().Height - 25) / 10
```

})

```
    PdfTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, 50, 35, 460, pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1)) 'X Y départ en bas à gauche? plus yPos est au plus le texte est haut

    PdfTable.CompleteRow()

    pdfStamper.Close()
    MsgBox("Exported")
```

Answer (score 0):

`PdfTable.WriteSelectedRows` is documented as

```c#
/**
* Writes the selected rows to the document.
* 
* @param rowStart   the first row to be written, zero index
* @param rowEnd     the last row to be written + 1. If it is -1 all the
*                   rows to the end are written
* @param xPos       the x write coodinate
* @param yPos       the y write coodinate
* @param canvas     the <CODE>PdfContentByte</CODE> where the rows will
*                   be written to
* @return the y coordinate position of the bottom of the last row
*/
virtual public float WriteSelectedRows(int rowStart, int rowEnd, float xPos, float yPos, PdfContentByte canvas)
```

You use

```vb
PdfTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, 50, 35, 460, pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1)) 'X Y départ en bas à gauche? plus yPos est au plus le texte est haut
```

Thus, you explicitly only draw the first 50 rows of your table over page 1 and completely ignore the remaining rows.

Your observation, therefore,

> when my content goes beyong 1 page it does not create and append text to next page.

is exactly what is to be expected.

To draw all the rows, you can iterate and draw rows 50..99 over page 2, 100..149 over page 3, etc. `PdfPTable` has a property `Size` returning the number of rows in the table; you can use this to determine how often you have to loop.

If the document you loaded into your `PdfReader` does not have enough pages, you can add extra blank pages using `PdfStamper.InsertPage`.